# Can't hide window PYQT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

So basically, I am designing a network application that performs cloud computations. When the user logs in, i want to hide the log in page and show the other page. This works great if the user does not open the sign up page first. If the user opens the sign up page and tries to log in again, i am given the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\charb\Documents\UNI\Programming\workspace\Cloud
>   Computations\src\SignIn.py", line 24, in isAuthenticated
>       MainWindow.hide() NameError: name 'MainWindow' is not defined

here is the piece of code causing the error (in the login page code):

```
def isAuthenticated(self):
    if ClientFunctions.signIn(self.usernameField.text(), self.passwordField.text()):
        self.flag = True
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = mainpage.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.myusername= self.usernameField.text()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
        MainWindow.hide()
    else: 
        self.errorLabel.show()
```

here is the the code of opening the sign up page in the login code:

```
def openSignUpWindow(self):
    global window
    window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = SignUp.Ui_Dialog()
    self.ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
```

And this is how i open the login window from the sign up window:

```
def openSignInWindow(self):
    self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    self.ui = SignIn.Ui_MainWindow()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
    self.window.show()
```

The code is generated by QT Designer (pyuic5)

here is the login code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import SignUp 
import ClientFunctions
import mainpage
username = None
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    flag = False
    def isAuthenticated(self):
        if ClientFunctions.signIn(self.usernameField.text(), self.passwordField.text()):
            self.flag = True
            self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
            self.ui = mainpage.Ui_MainWindow()
            self.ui.myusername= self.usernameField.text()
            self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
            self.window.show()
            MainWindow.hide()
        else: 
            self.errorLabel.show()


    def openSignUpWindow(self):
        global window
        window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = SignUp.Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(window)
        window.show()

    def hideSignUpWindow(self):
        global window
        window.hide()

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(450, 601)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(36, 48, 60);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.usernameField = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.usernameField.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(142, 260, 171, 22))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.usernameField.setPalette(palette)
        self.usernameField.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
        self.usernameField.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.usernameField.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.usernameField.setStyleSheet("background:white;\n"+"border:black;\n"+"border-radius:5px;")
        self.usernameField.setText("")
        self.usernameField.setReadOnly(False)
        self.usernameField.setObjectName("usernameField")
        self.passwordField = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.passwordField.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(142, 350, 171, 22))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.passwordField.setPalette(palette)
        self.passwordField.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
        self.passwordField.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.passwordField.setStyleSheet("background:white;\n"+"border:black;\n"+"border-radius:5px;")
        self.passwordField.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhHiddenText|QtCore.Qt.ImhNoAutoUppercase|QtCore.Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText|QtCore.Qt.ImhSensitiveData)
        self.passwordField.setText("")
        self.passwordField.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.passwordField.setReadOnly(False)
        self.passwordField.setObjectName("passwordField")
        self.usernameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.usernameLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(185, 220, 81, 20))
        self.usernameLabel.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.usernameLabel.setScaledContents(False)
        self.usernameLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.usernameLabel.setWordWrap(True)
        self.usernameLabel.setObjectName("usernameLabel")
        self.passwordLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.passwordLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(185, 310, 81, 20))
        self.passwordLabel.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.passwordLabel.setScaledContents(False)
        self.passwordLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.passwordLabel.setWordWrap(True)
        self.passwordLabel.setObjectName("passwordLabel")
        self.signInBut = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.signInBut.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(157, 410, 141, 28))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(45, 147, 107))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(45, 147, 107))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(45, 147, 107))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(45, 147, 107))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(45, 147, 107))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(45, 147, 107))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(45, 147, 107))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(45, 147, 107))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(45, 147, 107))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.signInBut.setPalette(palette)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(10)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.signInBut.setFont(font)
        self.signInBut.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"+"background-color: rgb(45, 147, 107);\n" + "border-radius:5px;")
        self.signInBut.setObjectName("signInBut")
        self.signInBut.clicked.connect(self.isAuthenticated) 
        self.gotoSignUp = QtWidgets.QCommandLinkButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.gotoSignUp.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 490, 301, 48))
        palette = QtGui.QPalette()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(36, 48, 60))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(36, 48, 60))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(36, 48, 60))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(36, 48, 60))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(36, 48, 60))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(36, 48, 60))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Inactive, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(36, 48, 60))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Button, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Text, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(255, 255, 255))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.ButtonText, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(36, 48, 60))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Base, brush)
        brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(36, 48, 60))
        brush.setStyle(QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern)
        palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Disabled, QtGui.QPalette.Window, brush)
        self.gotoSignUp.setPalette(palette)
        self.gotoSignUp.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n" + "border-radius:5px;")
        self.gotoSignUp.setObjectName("gotoSignUp")
        self.gotoSignUp.clicked.connect(self.openSignUpWindow)
        self.gotoSignUp.clicked.connect(MainWindow.hide)
        self.errorLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.errorLabel.setEnabled(True)
        self.errorLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(94, 460, 281, 21))
        self.errorLabel.setObjectName("errorLabel")
        self.errorLabel.hide()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 60, 251, 131))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/newPrefix/SignIn.jpg);")
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)





    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.usernameField.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Username"))
        self.passwordField.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Password"))
        self.usernameLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; color:#ffffff;\">Username</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.passwordLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" font-size:10pt; color:#ffffff;\">Password</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.signInBut.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sign In"))
        self.gotoSignUp.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Dont have an account? Sign Up here!"))
        self.errorLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\"><span style=\" color:#d10000;\">Username/Password combination does not exist</span></p></body></html>"))


import SignIn_rc

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: i cant add the full code there is a character limit here

Comment: i added the login code @eyllanesc